# build multi-dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

Im retrieving a Json dataset and need to build a javascript array called 'arrProducts'.  My code below is wrong but on the right lines. Can anybody help??

```
var allProducts = $.get("http://localhost:8888/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/search/search.json",
function(data) {
    var productsArray = data.products;
    var arrProducts = '';
    $.each(productsArray, function(index, product) {
        arrProducts['name'] = product.name;                        
        arrProducts['title'] = product.title;
        arrProducts['price'] = product.price;           
    });     
});
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `"` at the end of your URL

Comment: @freefaller I think it is a typo.

Comment: You can not use what the JSON object already has? You are loop through  somethings so it is array like. How is `arrProducts `different than `data.products`?

Comment: arrProducts needs to be an array, and you need to be giving it objects containing name title and price. productsArray is already in the format that you want.

Comment: @VisioN, you'd hope so, but I don't agree with making that assumption... especially if the OP is generating this code with non-syntax highlighting software (e.g. notepad). It's possible they've simply missed it, so I'd rather point it out and see if that is the case than update the question and possibly remove a major syntax error

Comment: How is `data` passed to the function. It should be an array of object literals, no?

Comment: can't you parse the JSON directly? What's in your JSON and what do you want in your js object?

Comment: @VisioN, sorry, but I have rolled-back this to the original revision of the question, because I do not believe anybody should **assume** that the code in the question has an error due to a "typo". [Please see this Meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152955) for my reasons.

Comment: Hi Guys, yes it was a typo. Sorry. The reason I need to process this data in a loop is to try and transform it from an Object.  I require the data to be a string array. This has not worked :-/ Does anyone have any ideas of how to transform a data object to an array?

Comment: @freefaller I don't mind that. Really. There was no need in court here. Even though I mostly agree with your point, but the cases are different. Seriously in Meta you haven't discussed in deep this particular question, only in general. It is quite obvious for me that the major problem here is not in the quote, since there are other more serious logical errors, and the question was mostly about that.

Comment: @freefaller Now we have a confirmation from the OP. Meta says I may do the correction after all.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it was a typo, richelliot, I will amend your question accordingly. @VisioN, I fully understand your position, and I agree that it was always unlikely to be the major problem.  I'm aware it wasn't a "deep discussion", but it was just the general concept of changing a typo I wanted to raise. Ah well, life goes on  :-)

Comment: Ah, sorry @VisionN, crossed comments... edit away :-)

Comment: @freefaller Good we agreed on the point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var allProducts = $.get("http://localhost:8888/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/search/search.json",
function(data) {
    var productsArray = data.products;
    var arrProducts = []; //This needs to be an array not a string.
    $.each(productsArray, function(index, product) {
        var prod = {};//make a new product for each iteration
        prod['name'] = product.name;                        
        prod['title'] = product.title;
        prod['price'] = product.price;    
        arrProducts.push(prod); //add the product to thearray of products       
    });     
});
```

As Kevin B points out, it looks like data.products is already an array of objects in the format you are going to, so this "conversion" seems pointless.

Comment: Yes it was pointless. I thought by looping thorough the data it may prevent it from being an object but unfortunately it still is. How do I transform it to a sting array?

Comment: Simple. Use: JSON.stringify(yourArray);

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
var allProducts = $.get("http://localhost:8888/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/search/search.json",
function(data) {
    var productsArray = data.products;
    var arrProducts = productsArray;
});
```

`productsArray` is already in the format you are trying to build, so you should really just use `data.products` directly.

```
var allProducts = $.get("http://localhost:8888/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/search/search.json",
function(data) {
    console.log(data.products);
});
```

Comment: Yes it was pointless. I thought by looping thorough the data it may prevent it from being an object but unfortunately it still is. How do I transform it to a sting array?

Comment: @richelliot An object is what you are calling a string array. JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays, it has objects and arrays, and arrays can contain objects.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create an array using this code:

```
var arrProducts = [];
```

The rest of your code will serve your purpose

But, as the comment states, this will create a three elements associative array which will be overwrittenin each iterarion. You need to re-think your structure: multidimensioanl array? array of objects?

Comment: No it will not, you will write over the same index over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
var arr;
var allProducts = $.getJSON("http://localhost:8888/web/app_dev.php/api/v1/search/search.json",
function(data) {
    arr = jQuery.makeArray(data);
});
```

Note :

You need to use getJSON method so that your end up with an already Parsed Object that you then can use in the callback. As for makeArray method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/